# Matrix class, sorting objects

Tags: c++, class, oop, matrix

I'm learning c++ now
I have task to create a class Matrix, where I have to sort Matrix by their sum of elements by bulb sorting
I've created some code, but it doesn't work
Can you help me and check what's going wrong?

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    int row;
    int column;
    int** M;
public:

    Matrix(int row, int column);
    Matrix(const Matrix& other);

    int getRow() const {
        return row;
    }

    int getColumn() const {
        return column;
    }

    int sum();
    void sortMatrixBySum(Matrix arr[]);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Matrix& other);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Matrix& other);
    friend void operator>(Matrix& m1, Matrix& m2);
    friend int operator-(Matrix& other);
    ~Matrix();
};
Matrix::Matrix(int row, int column) {
    this->row = row;
    this->column = column;
    M = new int* [row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        M[i] = new int[column];
    }
    cout << "--Constructor called-- " << endl;
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& other) {
    this ->row = other.row;
    this ->column = other.column;
    M = new int* [row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        M[i] = new int[column];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            M[i][j] = other.M[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "--Copy constructor called--" << endl;
};
int Matrix::sum() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            sum +=M[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Sum of the elements of matrix = " << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}

Matrix::~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        delete[] M[i];
    }
    delete[] M;
    cout << "--deconstructor called--" <<this<< endl;
}

//перегрузка <<
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  Matrix& other)
{
    os << "Overload <<:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < other.getRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < other.getColumn(); j++) {
            os << other.M[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        os << endl;
    }
    os << endl;
    return os;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Matrix& other) {
    cout << "Overload >>" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < other.getRow(); i++) {
        cout << "Enter the row number " << i + 1 << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < other.getColumn(); j++) {
            is >> other.M[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return is;
}
int main() {
    int numC, numR;
    cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin >> numR;
    cout << "Enter the number of column: ";
    cin >> numC;
    Matrix a(numR, numC);
    Matrix b(3, 3);
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    Matrix marr[4]{
        a,
        b,
        Matrix(3,2),
        Matrix(2,2)
    };
    cin >> marr[2];
    cin >> marr[3];
    a.sortMatrixBySum(marr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << marr[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's how i realise this sorting:

```
void Matrix::sortMatrixBySum(Matrix arr[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j<(sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr)); j++)
        {
            if (arr[j].sum() < arr[i].sum()) {
                Matrix temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

But also I don't know how to set a size of this array, like if it's right way to check size like (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))?

Comment: You have not completed the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Without an assignment operator, `arr[i] = arr[j];` and `arr[j] = temp;` are doomed to an ill fate.

Comment: No matter how much stuff it points at, the size of a pointer is always the same. You'll need to store the size of the array because the pointer, has no clue. It's just an address.